# How to convert a BufferedImage to gif in java

Tags: java, encoding, gif

I want to convert a BufferedImage to gif. I already converted BufferedImage to jpeg with a function and the output was Byte[] so I could send it over the inet with a socket connection.

I need a gif encode function similiar to this jpeg encode function:

```
public static byte[] getImageAsJPEG(BufferedImage image) throws ImageFormatException, IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    JPEGImageEncoder encoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(output);
    JPEGEncodeParam param = encoder.getDefaultJPEGEncodeParam(image);
    param.setQuality(0.9f, false);
    encoder.setJPEGEncodeParam(param);
    encoder.encode(image);

    return output.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: you can create using ImageIO, but notice that there are restrictions - see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592032/imageio-write-not-saving-out-as-gif-but-works-for-jpgs-and-pngs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
ImageIO.write(image, "GIF", output);
```

As in:

```
public static byte[] getImageAsGIF(BufferedImage image) throws ImageFormatException, IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    ImageIO.write(image, "GIF", output);

    return output.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: Thx that was easier than I thought :D